# How to filter Postgres enums by database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, enums

I can get enums, but I don't know how to filter it by database.

```
 SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_type t WHERE t.typtype = 'e';
```

That is the question — **how to filter enums by database?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_catalog.pg_type` is not a shared catalog. It's per-database. So by definition, if a row appears in `pg_type` it's in the database you are currently connected to.

The *schema* ("namespace") it's in is defined by the `typnamespace` column, which you can join to `pg_catalog.pg_namespace.oid` e.g.

```
select typname, nspname 
from pg_type 
inner join pg_namespace on pg_type.typnamespace = pg_namespace.oid 
where nspname = 'public';
```